# stop object referencing in as 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flash-cs4, flash-cs3, cs3

I have an object and a temp object now if i do
tempObj = obj

and change stuff in tempObj they changes have an effect on obj is there a way i can stop it from doing this?
Regards
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard behavior in many languages. When you do tempObj = obj you are NOT creating a duplicate object. You are creating another reference to the same object.

I don't think you can change this behavior, and certainly I don't think you should :)

What you need is creating another object, a duplicate of the original object. You can implement a function to do that. Maybe this can help
http://blog.comtaste.com/2007/10/improving_object_copy.html

Good luck!

Comment: Ok i will have a look into this cheers. I will let you now if it does what i need

Comment: with a bit more digging around but from your direction i got what i wanted cheers for the help fella

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is making a reference to the original object not a copy of the original. You should create a deep copy of your object. It seems that someone already wrote the steps to do so...

http://www.as3dp.com/2008/09/23/actionscript-30-clone-a-prelude-to-the-prototype-design-pattern/

Hope this helps